# i have one tabluar form table i need to place check box in it and some functionality to perform

Tags: codeigniter

controller

```
class Category extends Admin_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('category_model');
        }
    public function index(){
        $data['select'] = $this->category_model->getinfo();
        $this->load->view('category_view', $data);
    }
  }
?>
```

model

```
function getinfo(){
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query;
}
```

view

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <table border="1">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
             <td>lastname</td>
         </tr>
         <?php
         foreach ($select->result() as $row)
         {
            ?><tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>

            </tr>
         <?php }
         ?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i need to place multiple checkboxes so i can delete data via clicking it i also must have to check multiple checkbox at once(single check and check All both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
         <td>lastname</td>
         <td>*</td>
     </tr>
     <?php
     foreach ($select->result() as $row)
     {
        ?><tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_checkbox('action[]', $row->id); ?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php }
     ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

When you post this you will get array of id on which action need to be performed.

Comment: in action what should mention

Comment: it shows me error of form tag Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_checkbox()

Comment: @PranavShah you need to load the form helper in the controller function that loads this view `$this->load->helper('form');`

Comment: i did <td> <input type="checkbox"name="select[]" value="1"></td> is it true? it show me check boxes now i need to put one check box by clicking on it you can check all the single check boxes

Comment: @PranavShah it should be `<td> <input type="checkbox"name="select[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"></td>` if you dont want to use form helper. For the master checkbox please refer this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976846/check-uncheck-checkboxes-on-select-of-a-master-checkbox-in-jquery